# Functional dependency does not unify when bound in GADT

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies, gadt

In the following code:

```
class FD a b | a -> b

data Foo a where
  Foo :: FD a b => b -> Foo a

unFoo :: FD a b => Foo a -> b
unFoo (Foo x) = x
```

By common sense this should work, since `a` is the same in constraints in both GADT and function, and it determines `b`, however this doesn't compile with following error:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘b1’
      ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          Foo :: forall a b. FD a b => b -> Foo a,
        in an equation for ‘unFoo’
        at src/Lib.hs:13:8-12
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          unFoo :: forall a b. FD a b => Foo a -> b
        at src/Lib.hs:12:1-29
    • In the expression: x
      In an equation for ‘unFoo’: unFoo (Foo x) = x
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: b1 (bound at src/Lib.hs:13:12)
        unFoo :: Foo a -> b (bound at src/Lib.hs:13:1)
   |
13 | unFoo (Foo x) = x
   |                 ^
```

is there any good reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: The interactions between fundeps and GADTs, and those between injective type families and GADTs seem pretty bad at the moment. One would expect those to provide `T ~ U` constraints in many cases, but they apparently do not.

Comment: Seems certainly a valid (safe!) use case for `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think I'd prefer to rewrite it to use associated types before I reached for that footgun.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, you might think so, but you can satisfy the fundep checker in bogus ways. `instance MonadReader a U1 => MonadReader a U1 where ask = U1`. The type family and GADT machinery is much more careful.

Comment: @dfeuer EEEK! How is that working... in particular, how is it not just sending the typechecker in a loop until we get a stack overflow?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, you need to enable `UndecidableInstances`, at which point it's perfectly happy to tie a knot and assume you know what you're doing.

Comment: @dfeuer sure, but I'd thought that when I then write `ask :: U1 Int` it should try to unify `a ~ Int`, leading it to unifying `Int` with the `a` in `MonadReader a U1`, leading it to `MonadReader a U1`, ... – but never typecheck. Actually though, it looks like it never bothers with any such thing.

Answer (score 0):

> @chi The interactions between fundeps and GADTs, ... seem pretty bad at the moment.

I think it's more fundamental than that (and not just "at the moment", and not just for FunDeps).

Whatever the compiler infers about the type of `x` in

```
unFoo (Foo x) = ...
```

is only valid on the RHS, within the match on `(Foo x)`. Trying to return bare `x` would let any assumptions escape.

To compare a much older equivalent: before we had GADTs there were existentially-quantified data constructors, so

```
data Foo' a = forall b. FD a b => Foo' b

unFoo' :: FD a b => Foo' a -> b
unFoo' (Foo' x) = x
```

Fails to compile for the same reason.

Or trying to write an instance for `FD` gives the same `rigid type variable` trouble:

```
class FD a b | a -> b  where
  unFoom :: Foo a -> b
instance FD Int Bool  where
  unFoom (Foo x) = x    -- Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `b'
```

You might find Hugs' error message more revealing (for the existential datatype)

```
*** Because        : cannot instantiate Skolem constant
```

And I'm not convinced it's much to do with FunDeps. Compare

```
data FooN a where           
  FooN :: Num b => b -> FooN a

unFooN :: Num b => FooN a -> b
-- unFooN (FooN x) = x + 1                 -- rejected
unFooN (FooN x) = const undefined (x + 1)  -- accepted (but useless)

z = 1 + unFooN (FooN 7)                    -- accepted (for useless unFooN)
```

Rejected for the same reason: the assumption `x :: Num b => b` is valid only inside the match.

**Addit:** (in response to comments)

To expand on the "is only valid on the RHS, within the match on `(Foo x)`":

- In general, a GADT has many constructors, potentially each with different constraints.
- (Or indeed we might have a value with no constructor as in `(undefined :: Foo t)`.)
- So the match has to see the constructor before applying what's 'only valid on the RHS'.

A FunDep is treated as any other constraint for those purposes, so the OP's problem is like the `FooN` case. (The existential `b` remains scoped only on RHS.)

[@dfeuer's reworking](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/97e3d3f08f5a8cc468300b7529e27aff) using type families doesn't rely on scoping of tyvar `b`; the type family applies to `a`, which has scope throughout `unFoo`. That means `F a` has same scope. Because of the magic `~` superclass constraint, `unFoo`'s signature is equivalent to:

```
unfoo: Foo a -> F a
```

But here be dragons: [`F a` is not necessarily well-formed everywhere](https://repository.brynmawr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1075&context=compsci_pubs) [Section 3 'Totality Trap'], because code doesn't need evidence there's an applicable instance.

So I'm going to diametrically disagree with dfeuer: the FunDep *does* carry evidence, just like the `Num b` example, and that evidence can't escape the pattern match; type family `F a` doesn't carry evidence (of an instance match -- the `~` constraint is taken to hold without evidence), so `F a` is available throughout the scope of `a` -- "available" doesn't mean valid.

Comment: It's not about the presence of fundeps, but it's about what they (don't) mean. They're for inference only, not evidence. [A version using type families and equality constraints](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/97e3d3f08f5a8cc468300b7529e27aff) compiles just fine.

Comment: @dfeuer so please explain the `FooN` example: no FunDeps; and yet apparently not (enough) evidence for `Num b`.

Comment: Your example seems ... pretty much unrelated. I understand that evidence is only opened under pattern matches, but that has nothing to do with the OP's problem. The OP's problem is that fundeps don't carry evidence.

Comment: "The OP's problem" is that the code doesn't compile/gives a `rigid type variable` message. The problem with the `FooN` example is that the code doesn't compile/gives a `rigid type variable` message. I've put the same constraint on the GADT and on `unFooN`. `Num b =>` does carry evidence. If the examples are "unrelated ... [because] fundeps don't carry evidence.", why isn't the constraint on `FooN` carrying evidence?

Comment: "rigid type variable" is pretty generic. The OP's assumption was that the functional dependency on their `FD` class would behave like the equality constraint on the version I linked to. It does not.

Comment: I understand that in GADT, an evidence is valid only under pattern match and it cannot escape, however in case of `unFoo` it seems to be possible to determine that GADT's evidence and external evidence are the same, which doesn't seem to happen.


In case of `unFooN` this is not the case and `a` in `FooN a` is phantom

Comment: Fundeps definitely don't carry evidence. GHC doesn't use them for type checking at all—it only uses them for type *inference*.